# Publishing a Closed-Testing phase app to PlayStore using App Center

Tags: react-native, deployment, google-play, google-play-console, visual-studio-app-center

When connecting the store in the App Center there is this prerequisite.

[image]

I'm getting this error because there has to be at least one production release of your app to access it through the App Center

[image]

But the thing is the App is still in the closed testing phase, so how can I connect it with the App Center to automate deployments

**NOTE:** The app is already on the internal and closed testing tracks.

Answer (score 1):

The application has to complete Closed Testing before it can go to Production. After you have completed the closed testing, you will have to answer questions about your application like what changes you made from the feedback of tester and how is your app ready for production now.